# Function parameters containing data

Tags: jquery

In jQuery there exist functions' parameters, such as [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)'s callback's `data` or `textStatus`. Their values are not passed *to* the function but *by* the function. Is there a special name for this kind of parameters? Are they jQuery-specific or do they appear in plain JS as well?

I am familiar with the concept of callbacks. I wannt to get more insight on how does it work that the parameters have their values supplied by the code.

Comment: Is not jQuery specific at all

Comment: @charlietfl I am familiar with the concept of callbacks. I wannt to get more insight on how does it work that the parameters have their values supplied by the code.

Comment: by passing them in when the callback gets called. Very simple example https://jsfiddle.net/1hoxqp8a/

Comment: @charlietfl you totally don't understand what I am trying to find information about. I don't ask about usual callback arguments, supplied with values by the developer, but those such as mentioned in the original post

Comment: then you need a far better explanation of what you are trying to understand or accomplish. Question is very vague. Based on your edit the simple demo above answers that and is how the callbacks in `$.get` will pass data to your callback function also